# CSS Display property issue in Table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

There are two buttons in my code. one is for display:none and the other is to display Element again at same position.

When I am applying Display:none property through JavaScript on table row i.e . it works perfect.

but now I want to return  again on click. but it's not Displaying on it's accurate position.

TABLE

```
<table border="1">
<tr>          <td>name</td><td>cell</td>           </tr>
<tr id="rw">  <td>Ali</td><td>0341455454</td>      </tr>
<tr>          <td>irfan</td><td>033435783</td>     </tr>
</table>
```

Buttons

```
<input type="button" value=" click to display none " onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('rw').style.display='none';" />
<input type="button" value=" click to display back "  onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('rw').style.display='inline';" />
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vwuupnte/1/)

Comment: [check](https://jsfiddle.net/vwuupnte/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

display-inline is not a table element.
Use 'table-row' instead of 'inline'.

```
<input type="button" value=" click to display back "  onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('rw').style.display='table-row';" />
```

[Updated FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vwuupnte/2/)

Read more about Display options [from here](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use table-row instead of inline:

```
<input type="button" value=" click to display none " onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('rw').style.display='none';" />
<input type="button" value=" click to display back "  onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('rw').style.display='table-row';" />
```

[your updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwuupnte/3/)

Answer (score 0):

By default `<tr>` elements are `display: table-row`, not `display: inline`.

It is displaying incorrectly because you are giving it the wrong display model.

Answer (score 0):

Display:'none' OR display:' '  (empty) using

```
<input type="button" value="none" onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('rw').style.display='none';" />
<input type="button" value="view" onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('rw').style.display='';" />
```